# How to group an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am to make a code that:

1. Ask the user for the array size
2. Ask the user for integers
3. The program reverses the integers and group them.

I have already made a working code. My only problem is that I don't know how to group them. Can you help me?

**Ex1:
Input:**

```
5

8

2

3

7

5
```

**Output:**

```
[5,7]-[3]-[2,8]
```

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main{
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input= new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter size");
    int my_array = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter numbers to reverse");
    int[] intArray =new int[my_array];

for(int i=0;i<intArray.length;i++)
    {
        intArray[i]=input.nextInt();
    }
     for(int i=intArray.length-1;i>=0;i--)
     System.out.println(intArray[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by group?

Comment: @Pirate I meant that the output is grouped. It is shown in the example output above.

Comment: group on what bases?

Comment: Yes, the numbers were reversed

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible way to approach the problem.

1. Initialize a starting item `s` and previous item `p` to first item in array
2. Get next item and assign as current item `c`
3. Compare current item `c` to the previous `p` item.
4. If `c` is greater than `p`, assign `c` to `p`, and go to step `2`
5. If `c` is less than the `p`. Then you have a grouping of
   `[s,p]` (from start to previous)
6. If there are more items to process, assign `c` to `s` and `p` and repeat steps `2` thru `4`

You may need to take special steps to properly categorize the last item as either a `group of one item` or the `end of a group of items`.  Otherwise you could end up with a group like `[s,s]` which should be `[s]`.
That would require some special conditionals.  To help with this, you might consider saving the `previous` and `current` indices as you iterate thru the items.
Testing the index of `c` and `p` in relation to the size of the array will help to properly terminate the process.

It is important you first do this on paper, keeping track of all the values.  Then convert your paper solution to code.

Caveat. Sometimes it can be difficult to write out algorithms as above and mine may have flaws.  The purpose of this is to illustrate a mechanism on how to approach these types of programming problems.